# How to create a QJSValue object of type Error - throwing errors from QJSEngine

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt5, qjsengine

In Qt, does anyone know how to create a [QJSValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html) of type Error?

**Context**: I use [QJSEngine::evaluate()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#details) to execute JavaScript code written by a user in GUI created with QT. That JavaScript code calls a C++ function. According to the documentation the QJSEngine::evaluate() throws a script exception (QJSValue of type Error) only if there is an error in the JavaScript code. Therefore, if there is an error in the C++ function my approach is to return a QJSValue of type error. I am following that path becasue QJSEngine::evaluate does not catch C++ exceptions.

Here it is a code snippet of the intended functionality:

```
void CMainWindow::slot_ExecuteJVScript()
{
   myCppClass myObject(parameters); //It has a foo() method.
   QJSEngine myEngine;
   myEngine.globalObject().setProperty("myObj", myEngine.newQObject(&myObject)); //Now we can access the C++ object from JavaScript code.
   QString myScriptJS = "var X = myObj.foo()";  //Calling a C++ function from JavaScript
   QJSValue myValue = myEngine.evaluate(myScriptJS);
   if(myValue.isError())
   {
      //If there is an error in the JavaScript code we enter here
      //But I also wanto to enter here if there is an error in my foo() C++ function. 
   }
   else
   {
      //Do things with myValue
   }
}
```

Mini-Example of myCppClass::foo()

```
QJSValue myCppClass::foo()
{       
   if(something)
   {
       //Create a QJSValue myValue with some data
       return myValue;
   }
   else
   {   //ERROR
       //Create a QJSValue of type Error
       return myValueOfTypeError;
   }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd just say go ahead and submit a bug report [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/)...

Comment: I have seen that the main issue is submited: [request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39041). That it is that the QJSEngine lacks a way to catch errors thrown by C++ functions. Thank you.